# jmeter Beanshell PostProcessor remove header throws exception

Tags: testing, jmeter

When I was using BeanShell PostProcessor to delete the header，there is a problem
my code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header; 

sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization");
```

exception:

```
2017/05/18 15:24:52 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;   sampler.getHeaderManage . . . '' : Attempt to resolve method: getHeaderManager() on undefined variable or class name: sampler 

2017/05/18 15:24:52 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;   sampler.getHeaderManage . . . '' : Attempt to resolve method: getHeaderManager() on undefined variable or class name: sampler
```

somebody help me

Comment: Could you show us a bit more of the surrounding code, for example where and how sampler is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't have `sampler` shorthand in the PostProcessor, if you need to remove the header from the **previous** sampler the relevant code should look like:

   ```
   ctx.getCurrentSampler().getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization");
   ```

   - `ctx` is a shorthand to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance
   - be aware that PostProcessors are executed **after** requests so make sure your implementation is inline with what you are trying to achieve
2. If you need to remove the header **before** the request consider using PreProcessor instead. In this case you will be able to use `sampler` shorthand
3. I would recommend considering using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as an alternative to Beanshell as Groovy performance is much better at it is more Java-compliant.